# Unwanted noise (lines and dots) in ContourPlot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I have a `ContourPlot3D` that is a bit noisy on one side of the plot. I have tried `MaxRecursion` but actually it is of no use, `PlotPoints` help to some degree but even with a higher `PlotPoints` it is still there. You can see some dots and unwanted lines on the upper right portion of the plot. Any suggestions on how to resolve this? As a side question, is there a way to fix the viewing angle of the plot so that I don't have to align the plot every time?

```
ep = 10^-2;
m0 = 500;
g = 3;
F[u_, z_] := 1 - (m0 Exp[-g u]) z^4
intIndefinite[u_, z_] := Evaluate@Integrate[1/F[u, z], z]
int[u_, zz_] := Evaluate[intIndefinite[u, zz] - intIndefinite[u, ep]]
tPlane[x_, z_] := Evaluate[x - int[x, z]]
plot = ContourPlot3D[t == tPlane[x, z], {x, 0, 2}, {t, 0, 2}, {z, ep, 0.9}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 14], Mesh -> 5, ContourStyle -> Directive[Cyan, Opacity[0.7]], Lighting -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> {"x", "t ", "z "}, AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, Automatic}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {ep, 0.9}}, PlotPoints -> 30]
```

[image]

Comment: Why you used `ep = 10^-2;`? Cannot it be equal `0`?

Comment: @azerbajdzan The integral blows up at $z=0$, so $ep$ is just a cutoff to prevent that.

Comment: No, it is not. `z=0` is no problem, integral diverges at the curve you can see in the plot in my answer.

Comment: @azerbajdzan Does that really affect the behavior near the edges where the noise occurs?

Comment: It does not, but it simplifies the function expression.

Comment: I updated my answer with `ep=0`.

Answer (score 3):

These artefacts appear near the curve when `ArcTanh` and `ArcCoth` functions become non-real which is a discontinuity. It is around `x=1` when both `ArcTanh[x]` and `ArcCoth[x]` become infinity. So I think it would not be easy to get rid of the artifacts near this discontinuity.

The function I plotted is yours `tPlane[x, z]` I just used real part `Re` on it.

```
Plot3D[Re[
  x + 1/(2 Sqrt[2] 5^(3/4)) E^(
    3 x/4) (ArcCot[10 Sqrt[2] 5^(1/4) E^(3 x/4)] + 
      ArcCoth[10 Sqrt[2] 5^(1/4) E^(3 x/4)] - 
      ArcTan[Sqrt[2] 5^(3/4) E^(-3 x/4) z] - 
      ArcTanh[Sqrt[2] 5^(3/4) E^(-3 x/4) z])], {x, -6, 6}, {z, -6, 6},
  AxesLabel -> {x, z, t}, PlotPoints -> 100, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

**Update:**

With `ep=0` we have:

```
Plot3D[If[E^(3 x) > 500 z^4, 
  x - (E^(3 x/
     4) (ArcTan[Sqrt[2] 5^(3/4) E^(-3 x/4) z] + 
      ArcTanh[Sqrt[2] 5^(3/4) E^(-3 x/4) z]))/(
   2 Sqrt[2] 5^(3/4)), -10], {x, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}, 
 PlotPoints -> 200, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-5, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-9, 20}}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "z", "t"}, WorkingPrecision -> 100, 
 Method -> {"RotationControl" -> "ArcBall"}, 
 Exclusions -> {z == -(E^(3 x/4)/(Sqrt[2] 5^(3/4))), 
   z == E^(3 x/4)/(Sqrt[2] 5^(3/4))}, 
 ExclusionsStyle -> {None, Directive[Thick, Blue]}]
```

[image]

I do not have a quick answer how to get rid of the gray area, but with editing the full-form of the plot it is possible.

Comment: It seems like there are several surfaces for the solution, is it possible to just pick the surface corresponding to my plot? I remember there is a thread talking about a similar situation but I can't remember where, maybe that will eliminate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The distortions almost vanish if you plot from `{t, 0.5, 2}`. I know, this cuts off a small stripe at the right side of the plot, but I didn't find another way.

I also added a `Viewpoint` - option to avoid manual alignment.

```
ContourPlot3D[
 t == tPlane[x, z], {x, 0, 2}, {t, 0.5, 2}, {z, ep, 0.9},
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 14],
 Mesh -> 5,
 ContourStyle -> Directive[Cyan, Opacity[0.7]],
 Lighting -> Automatic, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "t ", "z "},
 AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, Automatic},
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {ep, 0.9}},
 PlotPoints -> 10,
 ViewPoint -> {-5, -2.4, 2.}]
```

[image]

Comment: That may seem an easy fix, but I need the range for $t$ in my code. The viewpoint option works though.